# Firebase won't retrieve data on real device, but works normally on emulator

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm developing a bus tracking app with firebase for storage.

My current method for retrieving a list of stations seems to be working fine in emulator

The method needs to get all documents in my Stations collection in firebase

[Firebase db colection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ptnv.png)

The method

### getAllBusStops()

```
  private void getAllBusStops()
    {


        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                .build();
        mDb.setFirestoreSettings(settings);

        CollectionReference busStopRef = mDb
                .collection(getString(R.string.collection_bus_stops));

        
        busStopRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            ArrayList<BusStop> tempBusStops = new ArrayList<>();
                int i = 0;
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult())
                {
                    BusStop busStop = doc.toObject(BusStop.class);

                    
                        GeoPoint getGeoFirebase = (GeoPoint) doc.get("position");
                        busStop.setPosition(getGeoFirebase);
                        tempBusStops.add(busStop);
                    
                    
                }

                dataViewModel.getmBusStopsLiveData().setValue(tempBusStops);
            }
        });

    
    }
```

### Location where `getAllBusStops` is called

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getAllBusStops();
    }
```

### Result on emulator running on api 27

[Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBnr8.png)

Debugging shows that data can be retrieved from firebase

[Debug Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IX4yz.png)

### The problem: No snapshots retrieved on real device

I tried connecting my real device for debugging, but the firebase function for getting the Stations collection `getAllBusStops()` seems to return no snapshot, I tried debugging and the number of snapshots from `task.getResult()` is 0, on the emulator device the number of snapshots retrieved are 3, exactly the same number of documents in my firebase db

In short, this line of code can get data normally on emulator when onComplete event is called

```
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult())
```

but on real device there's 0 snapshots

I've read on some posts that firebase requires permissions to be set, all requirement for permissions have been set in my project's manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
```

The real device has all permissions granted, yet there's still no data
I really don't understand what's going on, how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

1. what is your real device?
2. have you tried uninstalling the app / rebuilding the project?
3. are you using Firebase auth?
4. show us your Firestore security rules

Answer (score 0):

**Problem resolved**

I traced back the log and apparently internet connection was too weak to access firestore backend

Error Log:

```
W/Firestore: (21.5.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds
    
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
```

I switched to a stronger wifi and app is working A okay, which is a bit weird since my 4G connection has average speed of 4 MB/S. Will update more about this as I go along